# How to link html files in WebView?

Tags: android, html, android-studio, webview

I have a huge folder of htm files and a single html file with a href links to each of these htm files. I would like to create an android app, for personal use, to make browsing these files easier on a tablet.

I managed to load the main html file to WebView in Android Studio, but clicking any URL results in a crash, therefore I can't load any htm file through my html catalog.

I am not experienced in android programming, I only have some out-of-date experience in website creation back from the days when html with some css was enough, so I try to use my intuition. I might be missing something very obvious, but I didn't manage to solve my issue.

Maybe you'll be able to help me? Is it possible to redirect between html files via a href in WebView? Or maybe there is a simple way to bypass it? Coding the catalog from scratch is unfortunately out of question - there are thousands of htm files. Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
My code is as follows:

MainActivity.java

```
package a.my.app4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webz=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
        webz.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

index.html is just a huge list of a href links in the body section. It is loaded correctly to the WebView, even the simple formatting from css files is correct, but clicking the links leads to a crash. There are thousands of lines like that:

```
<a href="view-1.htm" title="file description">file title</a>
```

I also tried changing it that way (which would be problematic with thousands of lines...) but it didn't work either:

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/view-1.htm" title="file description">file title</a>
```

All the files are in the assets folder.

Comment: can you add your code where you are trying to load the html? It would be a starting point to allow anyone on SO to get more clearer picture and eventually help you get ideas

Comment: @Sagar thank you for the suggestion, the code is there now.

Comment: Can you also add your crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the StrictMode policy in order to expose the URI (in your case `view-1.html`). You can achieve your desired result as follows:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.wvWebView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
   <H1>Hello</H1>
   <a href="view1.html" title="file description">file title</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

**view1.html**

```
<html>
<body>
   <H1>Hello View 1</H1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I managed to solve my issue just a few moments before you answered by adding a single line to my MainActivity.java file:

    webz.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

It seems to work as needed. Is there anything incorrect with my method that could lead to any other problems?

Comment: oh. That's great! You can put it as an answer. You can also try my approach. Enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue in the future, I solved it by adding one line to the java file. I was missing something really obvious, indeed. I also added a code part to determine back button's behaviour.

MainActivity.java is now as follows:

```
package a.my.app4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webz=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
        webz.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        webz.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        WebView webz = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
        if (webz.canGoBack()) {
            webz.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```