# How to open html string "a href" to Webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

how can i open the html string that has `a href` on webview only instead of going on your browser?

i am using the LinkMovementMethod, this is okay on opening it on other app like video from youtube but i have some links that needs to be open only on webview.

here is a sample html string

```
String html_text =  "<h1>sample text</h1><p><small>February 1 1970</small></p><p class=\"text-center\"><img src=\"https://www.google.com\" /></p><p>sample (<a href=\"https://google.com\">here</a>).</p>"
```

i need the a href to be open only on webview.

here is my code

DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Html.ImageGetter {

    private TextView newsContentTv;
    private WebView newsWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_news);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        newsWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.newsWebView);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // add back arrow to toolbar
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        newsContentTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNewsContext);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        String news_content = i.getStringExtra("detail_content");

        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(news_content, this, null);
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString( Html.fromHtml(news_content) );
        newsContentTv.setText(spanned);

        newsContentTv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    }
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create an unencoded HTML string
// then convert the unencoded HTML string into bytes, encode
// it with Base64, and load the data.
String html_text =
 "<h1>sample text</h1><p><small>February 1 1970</small></p><p class=\"text-center\"><img src=\"https://www.google.com\" /></p><p>sample (<a href=\"https://google.com\">here</a>).</p>";
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(html_text.getBytes(),
    Base64.NO_PADDING);
newsWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Hi @amit it is still the same, it is just loading the content into html form. but the a href link is still going to browser.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092527/how-to-link-html-files-in-webview

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states you need to open the clicked url in your webview instead of navigating to browser. I can think of two ways to do this.

1. First case, if its not necessary to have a `Textview` to display the clickable link then you can load your string into the `WebView` itself (as others mentioned) and set a `WebViewClient` (this part is important)

```
  newsWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html_text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
  newsWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 // add below line to support youtube videos etc.
  newsWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  newsWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

so that any click keeps the navigation in the same `WebView`. Without the client it will navigate to the browser. But you should note this will load and replace the content inside, so your original link will not be there on screen.

2. Second case, if you need the clicks to be from the `TextView` simply setting `newsContentTv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` won't work as by default it will make the normal intent causing it to navigate to browser or related apps, you need to remove that. Then, you have to create a custom class extending `LinkMovementMethod` and override the touch event to load the url clicked into your webview as shown below:

```
public class CustomLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {

    private static CustomLinkMovementMethod instance;

    public static CustomLinkMovementMethod getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new CustomLinkMovementMethod();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            int x = (int) event.getX() - widget.getTotalPaddingLeft() + widget.getScrollX();
            int y = (int) event.getY() - widget.getTotalPaddingTop() + widget.getScrollY();
            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
            URLSpan[] urlSpans = buffer.getSpans(off, off, URLSpan.class);
            if (urlSpans.length != 0) {
                // You can check log to see if you are getting the url on click.
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(urlSpans[0].getURL()));

               /* If you've made this an inner class in your activity
                  you can directly load the url into your webview.
                  Else you will have to create listeners to get url in activity
                  on event trigger */
                newsWebView.loadData(urlSpans[0].getURL());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }
}
```

use this on the `TextView` like

```
   newsContentTv.setMovementMethod(CustomLinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

See if this works for you, hadn't expected the answer to become this long.